# Where does AWS CLI export files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I am trying to export an OpenAPI specification from AWS API Gateway using AWS CLI. The request looks like this:

> aws apigateway get-export --parameters extensions='apigateway'
> --rest-api-id x8yfzmmuqh --stage-name DEV --export-type swagger openapi.json

The response is the following:

> {
> "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
> "contentDisposition": "attachment; filename="swagger_2023-09-01T12:32:55Z.json"" }

I understand the export was successful. From where am I supposed to download the exported file? I have tried to use the AWS CLI GUI >> Download File feature by providing the filename but I get an error:

[image]

Comment: File name `openapi.json` should have been created in the same path where you had run the command.

Comment: It's in the folder where you ran the command.

Answer (score 0):

As others users commented, the actual file to download is not the own showed in the screenshot, but the one I provided which is "openapi.json". I was able to download this by using the ui option to download